# lm() within mutate() in group_by()

Tags: r, dplyr, lm

I'm looking for a way to add a column to my data table that consists of `residuals` from a `lm(a~b)` function computed separately for different levels of `c`

I've been suggested to look into `sort_by(c)` function but that doesn't seem to work with `lm(a~b)`

My working example data looks like this:

[image: outcome data frame]

Columns subject, trial and rt are within a `data.frame`, my goal is to compute `Zre_SPSS` (that I originally made in SPSS) but from a `R` function.

I've tried

```
data %<>% group_by (subject) %>% 
  mutate(Zre=residuals(lm(log(rt)~trial)))
```

but it doesn't work - Zre gets computed but not within each subject separately, rather for the entire data frame.

Anyone could please help me? I'm a complete R (and coding in general) newbie, so please forgive me if this question is stupid or a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24766450/lm-called-within-mutate), chances are I didn't understand other solutions or they where not solutions I looked for. Best regards.

As per Ben Bolker request here is R code to generate data from excel screen shot

```
#generate data
  subject<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3)
  subject<-factor(subject)
  trial<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6)
  rt<-c(300,305,290,315,320,320,350,355,330,365,370,370,560,565,570,575,560,570)

#Following variable is what I would get after using SPSS code
  ZreSPSS<-c(0.4207,0.44871,-1.7779,0.47787,0.47958,-0.04897,0.45954,0.45487,-1.7962,0.43034,0.41075,0.0407,-0.6037,0.0113,0.61928,1.22038,-1.32533,0.07806)

#make data frame
  sym<-data.frame(subject, trial, rt, ZreSPSS)
```

Comment: is there any chance you could post your example in a text/cut-and-pasteable form rather than as a screenshot?

Comment: of course. I attached code for generating data from the screen shot

Comment: You might want to look at `tidyr::nest` and a [quick blog blurb](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/06/13/tidyr-0-5-0/).

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27452491/save-residuals-with-dplyr) might help.

Comment: A model with `trial` on the RHS, and _not_ as a factor, doesn't seem to make much sense. Is this really the data you fit the SPSS model on?

Comment: @HongOoi yes, I belive I put that the right way - In general want to predict `log(rt)` (latency) from trial number `ln(log(rt)~trial)` within each participant and save residuals corresponding to each rt

Comment: What the model is doing is fitting a linear trend in `trial`, ie, `y = b0 + b1*trial` where b0 and b1 are the estimated coefficients. This would make sense if `trial` was a sequential thing, maybe measurements taken over time. Is that the case here?

Comment: correct. `trial` was sequential - in my original research there where 40 questions for each participant and response latency `rt` was measured. One typical thing happening there was, answers where taking longer as the experimental procedure continued. In order to reduce error variance, the main analysis was performed on latencies regression-adjusted for the effect of serial position, and this is what I'm trying to reproduce in `R` code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a bug in dplyr 0.5's `mutate`, where `lm` within a group will still try to use the full dataset. You can use `do` instead:

```
sym %>% group_by(subject) %>% do(
{
    r <- resid(lm(log(rt) ~ trial, data = .))
    data.frame(., r)
})
```

This still doesn't match your SPSS column, but it's the correct result for the data you've given. You can verify this by fitting the model manually for each subject and checking the residuals.

(Other flavours of residuals include `rstandard` for standardized and `rstudent` for studentized residuals. They still don't match your SPSS numbers, but might be what you're looking for.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions (`Zre_SPSS` is in fact `rstandard`) . Your code works but as you already saw it doesn't match SPSS output. I double checked it and data is identical, This is more then weird! Should I edit my question and post SPSS data file with some syntax for reference?

Comment: I know you must hate screenshots, but here is a proof of how it looked in spss [link]http://imgur.com/a/JHRPP[link]

Comment: What I just found is that your formula `rstandard(lm(log(rt) ~ trial)` matches SPSS output for studentized residuals but not for standarized residuals as in my screenshot above.

Comment: In place of the `do(...)` could alternately try  `mutate(resid = resid(lm(data.frame(log(rt), trial))))
`

Comment: @blazej what did you do to get the formula output to match what SPSS gave you?

Comment: I didn't match it - SPSS calculates ZRE scores differently that `rstandandard` in R. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40062482/standarized-residuals-in-spss-not-maching-r-rstandardlm

Answer (score 2):

Later version of `dplyr` seems able to handle this (tested with `dplyr` 0.7.4):

```
sym %>% group_by(subject) %>% do(
{
    r <- resid(lm(log(rt) ~ trial, data = .))
    data.frame(., r)
}) ->a

sym %>% group_by(subject) %>% mutate(

    r =  resid(lm(log(rt) ~ trial))
) ->b

all(a$r==b$r)  #->TRUE
```

another independent test

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/40061201/2292993
# https://stackoverflow.com/q/24766450/2292993
# https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2177

# tested with dplyr 0.7.4

# 1) do 
df = group_by(iris,Species) %>% do({
res = resid( lm(Sepal.Length~Petal.Length+Petal.Width, data=.) )
data.frame(., res)
})

# 2) group_by + mutate
# cannot have "data=." in lm
df2 = group_by(iris,Species) %>% mutate(
res = resid( lm(Sepal.Length~Petal.Length+Petal.Width) )
)

# 3) filter + mutate
df3 = filter(iris,Species=='setosa') %>% mutate(
res = resid( lm(Sepal.Length~Petal.Length+Petal.Width, data=.) )
)
df3 = bind_rows(df3,
filter(iris,Species=='versicolor') %>% mutate(
res = resid( lm(Sepal.Length~Petal.Length+Petal.Width, data=.) )
))
df3 = bind_rows(df3,
filter(iris,Species=='virginica') %>% mutate(
res = resid( lm(Sepal.Length~Petal.Length+Petal.Width, data=.) )
))

# 4) across all rows (should not be the same)
df4 = mutate(iris,
res = resid( lm(Sepal.Length~Petal.Length+Petal.Width, data=iris) )
)

# conclusion: all the same, except df4
all(df$res==df2$res)
all(df$res==df3$res)
df$res==df4$res
```